# Python nicest way to take boolean expression string apart

Tags: python

I have a boolean expression string, that I would like to take apart:

```
condition = "a and (b or (c and d))"
```

Or let's say:
I want to be able to access the string contents between two parenthesis.
I want following outcome:

```
"(b or (c and d))"
"(c and d)"
```

I've tried the following with regular expressions (not really working)

```
x = re.match(".*(\(.*\))", condition)
print x.group(1)
```

Question:
What is the nicest way to take a boolean expression string apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a parser:

```
 Condition ::= Term Condition'
 Condition' ::= epsilon | OR Term Condition'
 Term  ::=  Factor Term'
 Term' ::= epsilon | AND Factor Term'
 Factor ::= [ NOT ] Primary
 Primary ::= Literal | '(' Condition ')'
 Literal ::= Id
```

Comment: Don't you usually want to avoid left recursion? Also, your nonterminals `Condition` and `Term` can only produce infinite strings, since they have no base case.

Comment: how would this look without left recursion?

Comment: Although note that this grammar forces you to put parens around the argument to NOT: `NOT (1=2)` unless it is a literal `NOT p`

Answer (score 8):

This is the sort of thing you can't do with a simple regex. You need to actually parse the text. [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is apparently excellent for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone said, you need a parser.

If you don't want to install one, you can start from [this simple top-down parser](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm) (take the last code sample [here](http://svn.effbot.org/public/stuff/sandbox/topdown/tdop-4.py))

Remove everything not related to your need (+, -, *, /, is, lambda, if, else, ...). Just keep parenthesis, `and`, `or`.
You will get a binary tree structure generated from your expression.
The tokenizer use the build-in `tokenize` (`import tokenize`), which is a  lexical scanner for Python source code but works just fine for simple cases like yours.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirements are fairly simple, you don't really need a parser.
Matching parentheses can easily be achieved using a stack.

You could do something like the following:

```
condition = "a and (b or (c and d))"

stack = []

for c in condition:
    if c != ')':
        stack.append(c)
    else:
        d = c
        contents = []
        while d != '(':
            contents.insert(0, d)
            d = stack.pop()
        contents.insert(0, d)
        s = ''.join(contents)
        print(s)
        stack.append(s)
```

produces:

```
(c and d)
(b or (c and d))
```